# Getting value of checked radio button by name of radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I already looked at questions about this but I still can't do it. How would I get the value of these radio buttons? Am I not supposed to do it by name? HTML:

```
 <label for 'planet'>Planet:</label> <br>
  <input id ='mercury' type ='radio' name='planets' value='mercury'>Mercury<br>
   <input id ='venus'type ='radio' name='planets' value='venus'>Venus<br>
  <input id ='earth'type ='radio' name='planets' value='earth'>Earth<br>
  <input id ='mars'type ='radio' name='planets' value='mars'>Mars<br>
  <input id ='jupiter'type ='radio' name='planets' value='jupiter'>Jupiter<br>
  <input id ='saturn'type ='radio' name='planets' value='saturn'>Saturn<br>
  <input id ='uranus'type ='radio' name='planets' value='uranus'>Uranus<br>
  <input id ='neptune'type ='radio' name='planets' value='neptune'>Neptune<br><br>

  <button id='submit'>SUBMIT</button>
```

javascript:

```
$('#submit').on('click',function(){
  $("input:radio").attr("checked", false);
  var age = document.getElementById('age');
  age.value=' ';

  var checked = document.getElementsByName('planets').checked.value;
    alert(checked);
});
```

Comment: **Note:** Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr` when using boolean values

Comment: So basically first you uncheck all of them, then you're trying to get the checked ones ?

Comment: Do you want to get all the radio values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("input[name='planets']:checked").val()`

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/77A8P/)***

EDIT:

I see this line in your submit handler, this will uncheck all radio buttons, so don't do it..

`$("input:radio").attr("checked", false);`

Comment: I tried something like that and it just said 'undefined' and it still does with this

Comment: @Veronica - please take a look at the demo. If there is nothing checked, on click of submit it will give undefined, else gives out the value correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get value like this -

```
checked = $('input:radio[name="planets"]:checked').val();
```